# Spring Integration: can one call a gateway from within a header enricher?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need to make a number of calls to gateways and to then place the return payloads into headers.  These *gateway* calls are really sending a message to a channel behind which there is a chain.  It currently looks like this:

```
<int:channel id            = "call_api_a" />
<int:chain   input-channel = "call_api_a" >
    ...
</int:chain>

<int:channel id            = "call_api_b" />
<int:chain   input-channel = "call_api_b" >
    ...
</int:chain>
```

```
<int:gateway request-channel="call_api_a" />

<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="a" expression="payload" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int:gateway request-channel="call_api_b" />

<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="b" expression="payload" />
</int:header-enricher>
```

Is there an elegant way to embed the call to the gateway inside of the header-enricher?

Something like:

```
<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="a">
        <int:gateway request-channel="call_api_a" />
    </int:header>
</int:header-enricher>
```

I know that the above doesn't work but gives the sense of what I'd like to achieve.

Thanks for any pointers and best regards.

-aljo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not `<gateway>`, but like this:

```
<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="a"  ref="myGateway" method="gatewayMethod"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

The `<gateway>` is bean based on some service interface.
You just point in the `<header>` definition to that bean and its method to be called against your payload or message.

There is some explanation in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#header-enricher

Comment: In this case, the call to "gateway"

`<int:gateway request-channel="call_api_b" />`

is really calling a "channel" which has a message "chain" as a listener:

`<int:channel id="call_api_b" />` 
`<int:chain input-channel="call_api_b" >`
...
`</int:chain>`

I'm looking at `MessageChainHandler` but not finding an obvious method to use for the bean.  Any pointers?

Comment: I guess what I am really looking for is an in-line way of setting a header to be the value of the payload returned from sending a message to a message channel.

Comment: For that purpose I'd suggest to look into an `<enricher>` instead. It does exactly what you are asking - sends a request message to the channel and parses the reply for payload or header. See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#payload-enricher

Comment: The `<enricher>` looks good for calling a defined channel and defining the payload to be sent to that channel.  Two questions: 1) Is it possible to inhibit the update of the message payload upon return of the response message from the request channel?  I only want to update a header.  2) Can this call an asynchronous channel and then await the response?  thanks for the help.

Comment: If you don't specify any property, but just headers, then those new headers are going to be added to the reply message. The payload of that reply message is a payload of input message anyway. Therefor it is not clear why is the question if you don't update the payload via properties configuration.

Comment: In this case, I only want to update the header.  The `<header-enricher>` does not allow me to reference a `channel` directly hence required defining an additional `gateway` and using the bean operator `@bean.method(payload.x.y).payload` in the expression to call the channel, which is a bit clumsy and adds additional technical debt.  The `<enricher>`, on the other hand, does allow me to reference the `channel` directly.  It might be useful to make a channel reference available directly within `<header-enricher>`.

Comment: Well, I won't say that this is not possible to implement, but it would make this component looking too complicated causing some  technical debt. There are `ref` and `method` general attributes of the `<header-enricher>` which is called once. Such a method may produce a map of headers and it is fully up to you how you obtain every single entry of the headers to add. Instead of a gateway you may use a `MessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive()` instead for particular destination to reach.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "additional gateway definition" is the way to go on this one.  Thanks, @artem-bilan, for pointing me in the right direction.

I want to call to my chain-channel directly from a header-enricher.
If my chain-channel is:

```
<int:channel id            = "call_api_a" />
<int:chain   input-channel = "call_api_a" >
    ...
</int:chain>
```

Define somewhere in the Java add your gateway interface.

```
package com.app.wonderful;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyChainChannelGatewayMethod {
    Message<?> callChainChannel(Message<?> message) throws MessageException; 
}
```

Define a gateway that points to your chain-channel:

```
<int:gateway default-request-channel = "call_api_a"
             id                      = "call_api_a_GW"
             service-interface.      = "com.app.wonderful.MyChainChannelGatewayMethod" />
```

Then you can call your gateway in-line from the SpEL expression in the header-enricher:

```
<int:header-enricher >
    <int:header name="a"  expression="@call_api_a_GW(#root).payload" />
</int:header>
```

Does the trick for me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

@artem-bilan's suggestion to use `<enricher>` instead of `<header-enricher>` leads to a solution that obviates the Java interface signatures by addressing directly a channel.

```
<int:channel id            = "call_api_a" />
<int:chain   input-channel = "call_api_a" >
    ...
</int:chain>
```

We can call this channel from an `<enricher>`.  Here, for simplicity, the `<enricher>` component is part of a chain, but that is not a requirement:

```
<int:chain ...>

    <int:enricher request-channel="call_api_a" 
                  request-payload-expression="payload" >
        <int:header name="a" expression="payload" />
    </int:enricher>

</int:chain>
```

Thanks again for the pointers.